# I would like to get an idea of who first said "I will not dignify that question with an answer."

Tags: phrases, expressions

I don't know if that is even a quote, maybe just something many have said but I am interested at least to establish a date before 1960 on its appearance.

Comment: [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dignify+that+with+a+response%2Cdignify+that+question+with%2Cnot+going+to+dignify+that&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdignify%20that%20with%20a%20response%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdignify%20that%20question%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnot%20going%20to%20dignify%20that%3B%2Cc0) suggest 1963 as lift-off date. But you should have dignified your own question.

Comment: Thanks, had no idea of this service. I had honestly believed I invented the phrase but this dispels that notion. Now I just want to know if LBJ invented pouring piss out of a boot even if instructions were on the heel...

Comment: The earliest use I find is from the 1946 report of debates in Canada's House of Commons. "Mr. ABBOTT: I do not think I am going to dignify that further question with an answer." But Google Books offers many earlier refusals to dignify accusations, attacks, comments, charges, and "letters of an offensive character" with an answer.

Comment: I have to believe that this one has been re-invented several times, in various forms.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, the phrase appears to be much older than 1960 in a very similar construction.  An early use appeared in **1904**

> "But what about his opponent? I asked the nespaper reporters two or three days ago to go to Judge Parker and ask if he had not been interested in a trust, either as promoter or stockholder, or both.  His reply was that **he would not dignify the question with an answer**.

- [The Akron Beacon Journal (Akron, Ohio)04 Nov 1904, Fri](https://www.newspapers.com/image/228070589/?terms=%22dignify%2Bthat%2Bquestion%2Bwith%2Ban%2Banswer%22)

An earlier variant, replacing "question" with "remark," appeared in **1877**.

> Mr Cockrell thought that a little attention to the Constitution of the United States would have made the case perfectly plain.  He read the clause of the Constitution and the law, and said the course to be pursued was perfectly plain, and if Vermont did not know by this time how to comply with the law. [sic]
>
> Mr. Edmunds said he would use up his ten minutes by calling up the yeas and nays.  He **would not dignify this question by a single remark**.

- [National Republican (Washington, District of Columbia)01 Mar 1877, Thu](https://www.newspapers.com/image/77951367/?terms=%22dignify%2Bthe%2Bquestion%22)

Finally, a much looser construction, "dignify it by a better epithet," can be found in **1820**.

> > If a transaction of this nature had happened among individuals, mankind by common consent, **would not dignify it by a better epithet** than swindling.

- [The Hillsborough Recorder (Hillsborough, North Carolina)26 Apr 1820, Wed](https://www.newspapers.com/image/62835496/?terms=dignify%2Bquestion%2Banswer)

As pointed out in [Trischa's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/407466/228732), more loose constructions date back further and further, into the 17th century at least.  But the phrase even in its contemporary form appears to be as early as the start of the 20th century.

Answer (score 2):

An OED quote suggests a rationale at least, if that is of interest: anything you take pains over (e.g. an answer), you thereby dignify:

1665 Glanvill Scepsis Sci. 80 'Tis usual for men to dignifie what they have bestowed pains upon.]

RE Google NGRAM -- if you try for "dignify with an answer" it takes you back to 1900-odd rather than 1963.

Comment: Hello. Trischa. If you post an early example you access via your well-selected Ngram, this becomes a really good answer.

Answer (score 1):

One early instance of a person refusing to respond to a tendentious question is recorded in an item headed "[Congressional Silence](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn85026309/1869-04-07/ed-1/seq-2/#date1=1789&index=0&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&words=dignify+reply&proxdistance=5&date2=1870&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=that+he+will+not+dignify+it+with+a+reply&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1)," in the *Urbana [Ohio] Union* (April 7, 1869), as follows:

> For two days the standing subject of conversation in all political circles has been the specific charge of corruption, made in the boldest and most pointed manner by the Evening Post against Senator Fenton. For two days the question, "Will the Senate agree to a repeal?" gave place to this—**"Did Fenton get that twenty thousand dollars, and will he say anything?"**
>
> M. Fenton's friends assert that he will take no notice of it; that **he will not dignify it with a reply**; that Senators can not be expected to follow all the scribblers for the press, and so on.

This is not particularly close to the letter of "I will not dignify that question with an answer," but it is remarkably close to the spirit of it. In fact, it does the quote one better (at least logically) in that the offended party's supporters made the dismissive statement, instead of putting the man himself in the awkward position of responding to (and perhaps dignifying) the question by saying that he will not dignify the question with an response.

The nonresponse response by Fenton's backers is not, however, the first of its kind in the Library of Congress's Chronicling America newspaper database. Almost a decade earlier, in an "[Holding Office Under Lincoln](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn82014511/1860-10-16/ed-1/seq-2/#date1=1789&index=2&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&words=dignify+reply&proxdistance=5&date2=1870&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=that+he+will+not+dignify+it+with+a+reply&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1)," an item originally printed in the *Nashville [Tennessee] Patriot* and reprinted in the *Chicago Press and Tribune* (October 16, 1860), this specimen appears:

> We expressed the opinion last week that, should Lincoln be elected, he would continue the present Democratic office holders in the South in office, and we thought it quite probable that none of them would decline to serve, We have seen nothing from any of them yet to to cause us to abandon or modify this opinion. On the other hand, we have seen something to strengthen it. The fire eating editor of the *Avalanche* is postmaster at Memphis. The *Appeal*, a few days ago, plied him with the following interrogatory:
>
> "**Do you believe that a Southern man can hold office under a Black Republican Administration without self-disgrace? and if so, would you hold one yourself**?"
>
> In response the *Avalanche* said:
>
> "The last interrogatory of the Appeal we regard as an unjustifiable effort to drag the private affairs of the senior editor of this paper into this discussion, and **we will not dignify it with a reply**!"

The *Appeal* was not slow to observe that this nonreply was indeed a reply. Indeed, it referred to the response as "a species of artful dodging that would do credit to the adroitness of a leather-wing bat." Nevertheless, the *Appeal*'s reaction suggests that the tactical nonreply reply was something of a novelty in 1860. Today, no one would think of complimenting a speaker on his or her originality and adroitness for trotting out the old "I won't dignify that question with an answer" cliché.